# How to create a Eslint Rules to validate only capital constant variable

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

**Is there any Eslint rules which is used to validate to only allow the capital variable in defined `.js` files..**

Eslint has a `Require CamelCase (camelcase)` rules and use `"properties": "always"`  to validate camelCase imports. I'm wondering if there is similar type of rules or simply can I create one to validate below example.

`cosntant.js`

```js
// valid
export const EDIT_FORM = "EDIT_FORM" 

// invalid 'warning'
export const edit_form = "EDIT_FORM"
```

Comment: The rule [id-match](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/id-match) can validate all caps identifiers, but it seems there is no way to make it operate only on `const` declarations.

Comment: @GOTO0 can we only specify a `eslint rules` for a specific folder and extends it in `eslint` main file ?

Comment: Certainly. Just create an `.eslintrc.js` file inside that folder with only one rule configured. The other settings will be inherited automatically.